# What is the /etc/init/failsafe.conf file for?

Tags: boot, networking

What exactly is the `/etc/init/failsafe.conf` for? I have disabled the sleep timers in my failsafe.conf file which get make a faster boot up time. Are there any downsides? The only things I could come up with looking around was a this description from [this link which complains that the wait time isn't high enough.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/839595)

> I think that [30] is really to small a number. You're only safeguarding against the case where a user had an entry in /etc/network/interfaces that where the device was removed or is not connected. Thats a very rare case. Increasing the timeout to 60 seconds would make it less likely to have a false positive and have rc-sysinit start early. (Ie, the case where a dhcp took 35 seconds).

Inside of the failsafe.conf file itself states

> ```
> # The point here is to wait for 2 minutes before forcibly booting
> # the system. Anything that is in an "or" condition with 'started
> # failsafe' in rc-sysinit deserves consideration for mentioning in
> # these messages. currently only static-network-up counts for that.
> ```

I don't believe rc-sysinit depends on the network.

What purposes does `/etc/init/failsafe.conf` serve?

Comment: http://pherricoxide.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/all-about-network-configuration-in-ubuntu-server-12-0412-10/

rc-sysinit might not depend on the network, but it seems Upstart does.

Answer (score 4):

One purpose for failsafe.conf is to prevents problems like this one with slow DHCP servers: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/838968

You shouldn't hack at the sleep timer. The problem is probably that you have an `auto [ifname]` line in your /etc/network/interfaces file for an interface that doesn't get an address. This frequently happens if you install using a wired connection, and then stop using that wired connection in favor of another one (e.g. wlan).